# Differentiating between delegation and undelegation

Tags: tzkt

I am trying to get details about my tezos staking transactions through ghostnet tzkt indexer.
tried hitting https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/operations/delegations?sender=tz1UuLNVosJQuDoYmo66RoxPcZjGxRQ6bLTJ api .It returns all the delegations operations.But i am unable to distingush between delgation and undelegation operation. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can understand what's happened just by looking at `prevDelegate` -> `newDelegate` pattern. Like

1. `null` -> `not null` - this is delegation to a new baker.
2. `not null` -> `not null` - this is re-delegation to another baker.
3. `not null` -> `null` - this is delegation cancellation.
4. `null` -> `null` - this does nothing :)